# jQuery Templates and Razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can someone shed some light on how these compare/complement each other in the context of an ASP.NET MVC application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Razor builds HTML on the server side and jQuery templates builds HTML on the client. You would use Razor to build the basic structure and initial display of the page and use jQuery templates to update the page when you make AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks Brian, would be great if I could find a blog post showing these two creatures in unison :-)